# What is Plyr version of dplyr rowwise()

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

Does anyone know if there is a plyr way to apply: `rowwise() %>% mutate()` from dplyr?

I understand dplyr is a more updated version of plyr but working with a old custom made script built in plyr. Whenever I load dplyr it cause the plyr portion of the script to break.

Comment: Instead of loading `plyr` and/or `dplyr` with `library`, you could call them with double colon notation (`::`) so there's no namespace collisions

Comment: I don't use `plyr` so I can't provide an answer, but one work-around might be to use dplyr without loading the library, i.e. call `dplyr::rowwise()` to use the function.